# What's the cost of typeid?

Tags: c++, c++11, type-erasure

I'm considering a type erasure setup that uses typeid to resolve the type like so...

```
struct BaseThing
{
    virtual ~BaseThing() = 0 {}
};

template<typename T>
struct Thing : public BaseThing
{
    T x;
};

struct A{};
struct B{};

int main() 
{
    BaseThing* pThing = new Thing<B>();
    const std::type_info& x = typeid(*pThing);

    if( x == typeid(Thing<B>))
    {
        std::cout << "pThing is a Thing<B>!\n";
        Thing<B>* pB = static_cast<Thing<B>*>(pThing);
    }
    else if( x == typeid(Thing<A>))
    {
        std::cout << "pThing is a Thing<A>!\n";
        Thing<A>* pA = static_cast<Thing<A>*>(pThing);
    }
}
```

I've never seen anyone else do this. The alternative would be for BaseThing to have a pure virtual GetID() which would be used to deduce the type instead of using typeid. In this situation, with only 1 level of inheritance, what's the cost of typeid vs the cost of a virtual function call? I know typeid uses the vtable somehow, but how exactly does it work?

This would be desirable instead of GetID() because it takes quite a bit of hackery to try to make sure the IDs are unique *and* deterministic.

Comment: Originally, virtual inheritance was designed to avoid just the kind of switch or if-else-chain you are having in your main function. This switch is horribly error prone if someone forgets to add an else. Are you perfectly sure virtual dispatch or double dispatch won't do the job in your case?

Comment: Boost.Any uses `typeid` (in combination with `static_cast`) alright. User code uses the `get` function though, and doesn't bother with typeid. - Actually you might just as well use it, instead of rolling your own, as it does more for you (cloning and managing dynamic memory).

Comment: @thiton Consider most of the event handler methods in the world today - they almost all have a switch or if/else chain equivalent to the above.

Comment: @visitor Boost.Any looks perfect, except it's not updated for rvalue references, it could benefit from a make_any the way shared_ptr has a make_shared, and any_cast doesn't properly replace dynamic_cast (see celtschk's answer below for why).

Comment: @Dave: I don't get the point about dynamic_cast. There are no intermediate types in Boost.Any.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Typically, you don't just want to know the type, but also do something with the object as that type.  In that case, dynamic_cast is more useful:

```
int main() 
{
    BaseThing* pThing = new Thing<B>();

    if(Thing<B>* pThingB = dynamic_cast<Thing<B>*>(pThing)) {
    {
        // Do something with pThingB
    }
    else if(Thing<A>* pThingA = dynamic_cast<Thing<A>*>(pThing)) {
    {
        // Do something with pThingA
    }
}
```

I think this is why you rarely see typeid used in practice.

Update:

Since this question concerns performance.  I ran some benchmarks on g++ 4.5.1.  With this code:

```
struct Base {
  virtual ~Base() { }
  virtual int id() const = 0;
};

template <class T> struct Id;

template<> struct Id<int> { static const int value = 1; };
template<> struct Id<float> { static const int value = 2; };
template<> struct Id<char> { static const int value = 3; };
template<> struct Id<unsigned long> { static const int value = 4; };

template <class T>
struct Derived : Base {
  virtual int id() const { return Id<T>::value; }
};

static const int count = 100000000;

static int test1(Base *bp)
{
  int total = 0;
  for (int iter=0; iter!=count; ++iter) {
    if (Derived<int>* dp = dynamic_cast<Derived<int>*>(bp)) {
      total += 5;
    }
    else if (Derived<float> *dp = dynamic_cast<Derived<float>*>(bp)) {
      total += 7;
    }
    else if (Derived<char> *dp = dynamic_cast<Derived<char>*>(bp)) {
      total += 2;
    }
    else if (
      Derived<unsigned long> *dp = dynamic_cast<Derived<unsigned long>*>(bp)
    ) {
      total += 9;
    }
  }
  return total;
}

static int test2(Base *bp)
{
  int total = 0;
  for (int iter=0; iter!=count; ++iter) {
    const std::type_info& type = typeid(*bp);

    if (type==typeid(Derived<int>)) {
      total += 5;
    }
    else if (type==typeid(Derived<float>)) {
      total += 7;
    }
    else if (type==typeid(Derived<char>)) {
      total += 2;
    }
    else if (type==typeid(Derived<unsigned long>)) {
      total += 9;
    }
  }
  return total;
}

static int test3(Base *bp)
{
  int total = 0;
  for (int iter=0; iter!=count; ++iter) {
    int id = bp->id();
    switch (id) {
      case 1: total += 5; break;
      case 2: total += 7; break;
      case 3: total += 2; break;
      case 4: total += 9; break;
    }
  }
  return total;
}
```

Without optimization, I got these runtimes:

```
test1: 2.277s
test2: 0.629s
test3: 0.469s
```

With optimization -O2, I got these runtimes:

```
test1: 0.118s
test2: 0.220s
test3: 0.290s
```

So it appears that dynamic_cast is the fastest method when using optimization with this compiler.

Comment: I wouldn't need to use dynamic cast if I knew the type though - So in the first if I would do: `Thing<B>* pB = static_cast<Thing<B>*>(pThing);`. Using typeid and static_cast would be a lot faster than n dynamic_casts.

Comment: @Dave Why should `typeid` be faster than `dynamic_cast`? Of course in your case you know the type (because of the `typeid`), but once `dynamic_cast` returns non-0 (or doesn't throw) you know the type, too and already got your cast.

Comment: According to visitor (commenter of the main question) what I just said is how Boost.Any does it, heh. typeid would be faster because you only do it once instead of n times.

Comment: @Dave: Yes, if there are a lot of cases and performance is an issue, I see your point.

Comment: @Dave: Interestingly, I ran a performance test and compared using dynamic cast, typeid, and virtual functions.  Without optimization, I got runtimes of 2.27s, 0.63s, and 0.47s respectively.  With optimization -O2, I got runtimes of 0.12s, 0.22s, and .29s respectively.  This is using g++ 4.5.1.

Comment: @VaughnCato Try removing all the assignments out of the loops in each of those tests, they differ in number and type on each test. Also, what does your `main` look like? Do you call each test 4 times(one for each type)? Those are interesting results though, why does dynamic_cast get so fast? What are you using to time it?

Comment: @Dave: His loops are virtually identical, except for some extraneous variables in the `dynamic_cast` case that the optimizer certainly removed.  As for why `dynamic_cast` "got so fast"... you are apparently under the mistaken assumption that `dynamic_cast` is slow.  It isn't, unless you're using an antique compiler.  For a shallow inheritance tree, it is as simple as comparing a few pointers.  And since `typeid` is used so rarely, I wouldn't be surprised to find that its routines are simply not as well written as those of `dynamic_cast`.

Comment: @Dave: I'm passing a command line argument indicating which test to run, and then checking it in main() and calling the appropriate test.  I then use the "time" command to check the runtimes for each case.

Comment: That's fun because I tried to run those testes with g++-4.7 and the result with -O2 are completely different 9.84s, 0.16s, 0.31. and it is even clearer in -O3: 5.71s, 0.002s, 0.311s. It seems quite fair in fact since the compiler can optimize the "switch" in test 2 and 3 while it has to perform every cast in test1. Here the compiler certainly get rid of polymorphism in test2 while inlining, then the result of typeid is known at compile time.

Comment: After looking a bit at the generated code. It seems that test2 does not even generate a loop, the result is know at compile time.

Comment: Move int id = bp->id(); out of loop - you will see performance increase

Comment: I've posted a real benchmark in my answer. The problem with Vaughn's benchmark is that compilers are *really really good* at identifying and hoisting loop invariants. Testing the same condition over and over in a loop is no different from testing it once at the top of the loop. And if the compiler sees you dropping `result` on the floor, that's even worse — there's no need to compile the function at all in that case!

Answer (score 31):

> The alternative would be for BaseThing to have a pure virtual `GetID()` which would be used to deduce the type instead of using typeid. In this situation, with only 1 level of inheritance, what's the cost of typeid vs the cost of a virtual function call? I know typeid uses the vtable somehow, but how exactly does it work?

On Linux and Mac, or anything else using the Itanium C++ ABI, `typeid(x)` compiles into two load instructions — it simply loads the vptr (that is, the address of some vtable) from the first 8 bytes of object `x`, and then loads the `-1`th pointer from that vtable. That pointer is `&typeid(x)`. This is one function call *less* expensive than calling a virtual method.

On Windows, it involves on the order of *four* load instructions and a couple of (negligible) ALU ops, because the Microsoft C++ ABI is [a bit more enterprisey](http://www.openrce.org/articles/img/igor2_rtti1.gif). ([source](http://www.openrce.org/articles/full_view/23)) This might end up being on par with a virtual method call, honestly. But that's still dirt cheap compared to a `dynamic_cast`.

A `dynamic_cast` involves a function call into the C++ runtime, which has a *lot* of loads and conditional branches and such.

So yes, exploiting `typeid` will be *much much* faster than `dynamic_cast`. Will it be *correct* for your use-case?— that's questionable. (See the other answers about Liskov substitutability and such.) But will it be *fast?*— yes.

Here, I took the toy benchmark code from Vaughn's highly-rated answer and made it into [an actual benchmark](https://pastebin.com/9W1k9DD8), avoiding the obvious loop-hoisting optimization that borked all his timings. Result, for libc++abi on my Macbook:

```
$ g++ test.cc -lbenchmark -std=c++14; ./a.out
Run on (4 X 2400 MHz CPU s)
2017-06-27 20:44:12
Benchmark                   Time           CPU Iterations
---------------------------------------------------------
bench_dynamic_cast      70407 ns      70355 ns       9712
bench_typeid            31205 ns      31185 ns      21877
bench_id_method         30453 ns      29956 ns      25039

$ g++ test.cc -lbenchmark -std=c++14 -O3; ./a.out
Run on (4 X 2400 MHz CPU s)
2017-06-27 20:44:27
Benchmark                   Time           CPU Iterations
---------------------------------------------------------
bench_dynamic_cast      57613 ns      57591 ns      11441
bench_typeid            12930 ns      12844 ns      56370
bench_id_method         20942 ns      20585 ns      33965
```

(Lower `ns` is better. You can ignore the latter two columns: "CPU" just shows that it's spending all its time running and no time waiting, and "Iterations" is just the number of runs it took to get a good margin of error.)

You can see that `typeid` thrashes `dynamic_cast` even at `-O0`, but when you turn on optimizations, it does even better — because the compiler can optimize any code that *you* write. [All that ugly code hidden inside libc++abi's `__dynamic_cast` function](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/libcxxabi/blob/master/src/private_typeinfo.cpp#L618-L706) can't be optimized by the compiler any more than it already has been, so turning on `-O3` didn't help much.

Comment: Thank you! Glad to see that. I was wondering why dynamic cast appeared faster in Vaughn's answer.

Answer (score 3):

In almost all cases you don't want the exact type, but you want to make sure that it's of the given type *or any type derived from it*. If an object of a type derived from it cannot be substituted for an object of the type in question, then you are violating the [Liskov Substitution Principle](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) which is one of the most fundamental rules of proper OO design.